# Trigger ansible handler when a variable is changed

Tags: linux, centos7, ansible

I would like to trigger a handler when a variable is changed.

For example I have in mysql config file the innodb-log-file-size config item. I would like to do a couple of actions when this item is changed:

- ensure MySQL is running (we must start from a stable state)
- run in mysql: SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0
- stop MySQL
- move /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile[01] to a backup folder
- start MySQL
- check that MySQL is running fine by running a MySQL query

See also: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1265/3574

The only problem I have is how can I determine that a variable (actually some specific text) was changed in the configuration file.

I am interested in a generic approach how to solve this problem. For my particular case I have in mind a couple of solutions.

**Edit 1:**
I am using template module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to watch the file for changes using [incron](https://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en)d. For example (from the linked documenation)

> _You need to run program 'abc' with the full file path as an argument every time a file is changed in /var/mail. One of the solutions follows:

```
/var/mail IN_CLOSE_WRITE abc $@/$#
```

There [incrontab(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab) man page is also useful and contains further examples.

This will only be able to tell you that the file has changed (close_write) it won't be able to tell you what was changed. To find out what was changed I think you're going to need to write some scripts.

Comment: Interesting. This is an out of box solution. And I think it is better than doing this in Ansible as it can cover for potential manual changes. +1

Answer (score 3):

For a pure Ansible solution you could set the `innodb-log-file-size` with [lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) module

Like this:

```
- name: Set innodb-log-file-size for MySQL.
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/mysql/my.cnf
    line: 'innodb-log-file-size = {{ innodb_log_file_size }}'
  notify: restart mysql
```

You would then need to create a handler for each action you listed. The task above would only return `CHANGED` and trigger the configured `handlers` when the value of `innodb_log_file_size` changed.

I assuming here that you are using `template` module to create the mysql configuration. `template` module returns `CHANGED` when any parameter set via Ansible in the config file changed. `lineinfile` module enables you to trigger handlers for a specific change.

This strategy has however the bad side effect that you can't mix `template` and `lineinfile` module because in subsequent Ansible runs both task would always return `CHANGED` and therefor break idempotence of the play.

**edit**

After thinking a bit about the problem I would recommend the following strategy: check via `command` module, create via `template`, check again via command module and notify if value changed.

```
- name: Register innodb-log-file-size in my.cnf
  command: grep -Fxq "innodb-log-file-size" /etc/mysql/my.cnf
  register: innodb_log_file_size_pre
  always_run: True
  ignore_errors: True
  changed_when: False

- name: Create my.cnf via template.
  template:
    src: my.cnf.j2
    dest: /etc/mysql/my.cnf

- name: Restart mysql service when innodb_log_file_size changed
  debug: msg="Restart mysql to activate innodb_log_file_size change"
  when: innodb_log_file_size_pre !== innodb_log_file_size
  notify: restart mysql
```

Comment: You are right, I am using template module. but for those who are not using template module this is a good solution.

Comment: template is definitely the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the help received from the other answers I decided to move the option in a separate file and trigger the restart+log_expansion when this file is changed. Bellow are the details.

In /etc/my.cnf file, I added:

```
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

In roles/mysql/tasks/main.yml I added:

```
- name: Create /etc/my.cnf.d MySQL config dir
  file: state=directory name=/etc/my.cnf.d owner=mysql group=mysql mode="u=rwx,go=rx" setype=mysqld_etc_t

- name: Configure innodb_log_file
  template: dest=/etc/my.cnf.d/set_innodb_log_file.cnf src=set_innodb_log_file.cnf.j2 backup=yes mode="u=rw,go=r"
  when: innodb_log_file_size_mb is defined
  register: innodb_log_file

- name: Expand innodb_log_file
  include: expand-innodb-log-file.yml
  static: no
  when: innodb_log_file.changed
```

roles/mysql/tasks/expand-innodb-log-file.yml:

```
- name: Stop MySQL
  service: name=mysql state=stopped

- name: Rename old log files
  shell: |
    cd /var/lib/mysql/
    for file in ib_logfile*;do
      mv $file remove-me-$file
    done
  when: mysql_minor_version == 5

- name: Start MySQL
  service: name=mysql state=started

- name: Remove old log files
  shell: rm -f /var/lib/mysql/remove-me-ib_logfile*
  args:
    warn: no
  when: mysql_minor_version == 5
```

roles/mysql/templates/set_innodb_log_file.cnf.j2:

```
[mysqld]
innodb_log_file_size = {{ innodb_log_file_size_mb }}M
innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
```